How to remove Wrangler from a Cloudflare Pages project?
I have a Cloudflare Pages project that uses Wrangler to run a function locally. I've recently Dockerized the project and since the function uses Hono, I can run that locally using a Node container, so I do not need Wrangler anymore.
I removed the wrangler.toml file and pushed to main, but I still see the tool tips in their web UI saying that configuration for the function and the environment variables is being handled by the wrangler.toml file.


Is there any way to tell Cloudflare Pages that I'm no longer using wrangler.toml and release the locks on the settings?

did you uninstall wrangler?

@GTK good catch, I had not. I removed it and pushed but the settings are still not unlocked. There was an error in the build, however, so perhaps it needs to pass for the changes to take place.

@GTK unfortunately, it looks like the error is to do with a node compatibility flag which is set in the wrangler.toml or as an environment variable which I can't change because it's locked.

maybe clear the project cache?
